# 404 not found error for valid url

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, afnetworking

With afnetworking getting 404 not found for valid url. Same url is working good in post man.

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:[@"Bearer " stringByAppendingString:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"authKey"]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    [manager POST:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.fp.com/api/v1/vendor/NotifyConsumerAlbumIsCreated"] parameters:paramsDict success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        if(completion)
            completion(responseObject, YES);

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error is %@",error);
    }];
```

Xcode Console and Post man screenshots resply.
[image: Xcode Console]

Postman response

[image: Postman]

Comment: post man does not show the excat error , in our developement the set the AFHTTPRequestSerializer type

Comment: I think you are putting wrong url it's not "http://" instead put "https://"

Comment: i need use http only, you can check the postman screenshot

Answer (score 2):

If you do `curl` with the `-i` flag you will see you have an issue with your url:

```
$ curl -i -X POST http://api.fp.com/api/v1/vendor/NotifyConsumerAlbumIsCreated
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Wed, 02 Nov 2016 09:58:55 GMT
Location: https://www.friendslife.co.uk/
Content-Length: 0
X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.4 JSP/2.0
```